# Fastest way to get User's unread Messages

Tags: jakarta-ee, orm, mapping, ejb, named-query

Sorry for the title but I don't know how to summarize the question :\

I've got 2 entities, User and Message, mapped to my DB, and I want a quick way to get all the unread messages of a user.

Here's some code :

```
public class User implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
[cut]
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "dst")
private Collection<Message> rcv;
```

_

```
public class Message implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
[cut]
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "read")
private boolean read;
@JoinColumn(name = "dst", referencedColumnName = "username")
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private User dst;
```

So, basically, what I need to know is if there's any way to avoid a code like this :

```
List<Message> unread = new LinkedList<Message>();
for(Message m : rcv){
    if(!rcv.read){
        unread.add(rcv);
    }
}
```

I know that it can be done with a query, but I don't know how to use it in a Java EE project.

How do I have to write the query to have the unread messages of just the current instance of User and not ALL the unread messages from the table?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unread messages for user can be found for example with following query:

```
User currentUser = ...
List<Message> usersUnreadMessages  = em.createQuery(
            "SELECT m FROM Message m WHERE m.read=FALSE AND m.dst = :dst")
                .setParameter("dst", currentUser)
                .getResultList();
```